# How to add a bounding box filter to this leaflet WFS request?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, wfs

I use this function to add an interactive layer to my leaflet application. It works great in most browsers, but fails due to time-out error on certain networks and browsers.
The solution I think is to add a bounding box filter to this function. Could anybody tell me where to find the information or how to do this?

```
    var rootUrl = 'http://map.kecoviewer.com/geoserver/ows';

var defaultParameters = {
    service: 'WFS',
    version: '1.1.0',
    request: 'GetFeature',
    typeName: 'cresh:datazones_popup_mini',
    maxFeatures: 6505,
    outputFormat: 'text/javascript', 
    format_options: 'callback: getJson',
    srsName:'EPSG:4326'


};

var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);
$.ajax({
    jsonp : false,
    url: rootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
   jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
    success: handleJson
});

var group = new L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
var geojsonlayer;
var featureLayer = new L.GeoJSON();
var defaultStyle = {weight: 0,opacity: 0,fillOpacity: 0};
var highlightStyle = {color: '#f7f90e',weight: 3,opacity: 1,fillOpacity: 0};
var currentlayer; 
function handleJson(data) {
    geojsonlayer=L.geoJson(data, {
        onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
            layer.setStyle(defaultStyle);

            (function(layer, properties) {
              layer.on("click", function (e) {
                if (currentlayer) currentlayer.setStyle(defaultStyle); 
                layer.setStyle(highlightStyle);
                window.open("http:\/\/map.kecoviewer.com\/birtviewer\/run?__report=report\/datazone_story_ig.rptdesign&Datazone="+properties.dz,"story")
                currentlayer = layer;
            });

            })(layer, feature.properties);
}
    }).addTo(group);

}

function getJson(data) {
console.log("callback function fired");
}
```

Comment: What exactly is failing? The initial AJAX call or the `window.open`? Besides, your code is quite messed up at many places.

Comment: Well, strange enough. The thing actually works but is very slow (causing a timeout in some cases). My question is how can I do this better? At the moment I think it is loading all 6505 features, next the layer changes style plus opens an iframe when clicked. Can I limit the size of the geojsonlayer by using a bounding box filter? Any positive suggestions very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's the the loading of the geojson layer which is the slow bit, once it's loaded it is nice and fast.

Comment: Thank you for having formatted your code, it is much easier to read now! :-) By loading, do you mean the downloading from your AJAX call, or the processing to convert the `data` into an `L.geoJson` layer? In the first case, you would have to see what options your remote service offers. It looks like you use a `maxFeatures` option, it does not help? In the second case, you would have to split your `data` into smaller chunks and add them to your `L.geoJson` layer by interval.

Comment: I did try to change the maxfeatures to 1000 (from 6505), this made it faster, but only a small part of the map is now interactive. It would make sense if it was only the current view extent, just don't know how to set this.

Comment: See the [WFS Reference for GetFeature](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html#getfeature): `srsName:'EPSG:4326', bbox: 'bottomLat, leftLng, topLat, rightLng'` seems to be adequate.

Comment: But do you know how to set the bbox coordinates based on the current (moving) window?

Comment: Simply use [`map.getBounds()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-getbounds), maybe with a little bit of [padding](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds-pad). Once you have that latLngBounds, you could try the [`toBBoxString()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds-tobboxstring) as value for your "bbox" parameter. Then on map [move end event](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-moveend) re-send your request and replace your geoJson layer by the new data.

Comment: How to add the cluster without creating duplicates after moving the map?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/150571)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to set a min zoom where you start loading the wfs.
Then listen to the move-event of the map and grab the current-extent to make this extent part of the GetFeature-Request:

working jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/n5rsdhha/

( or fullscreen: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/n5rsdhha/embedded/result/ ... here the start-zoom could perhaps be even higher)

and important javascript-part here:

```
var start_at_zoom = 8;

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    // does this feature have a property named dz?
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.dz) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.dz);
    }
}

var featureLayer = new L.GeoJSON(
    null, {
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(map);
load_wfs();

function loadGeoJson(data) {
    // console.log(data);
    featureLayer.clearLayers();

    featureLayer.addData(data);

}

map.on('moveend', load_wfs);

function load_wfs() {
    if (map.getZoom() > start_at_zoom) {
        var geoJsonUrl = 'http://map.kecoviewer.com/geoserver/wfs';
        var defaultParameters = {
            service: 'WFS',
            version: '1.0.0',
            request: 'getFeature',
            typeName: 'cresh:datazones_popup_mini',
            maxFeatures: 3000,
            outputFormat: 'text/javascript',
            format_options: 'callback: getJson',
            srsName: 'EPSG:4326'
        };




        var customParams = {
            bbox: map.getBounds().toBBoxString()
        };
        var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters, customParams);
        console.log(geoJsonUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters));


        $.ajax({
            jsonp: false,
            url: geoJsonUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters),
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
            success: loadGeoJson
        });

    } else {
        alert("please zoom in to see the polygons!");
        featureLayer.clearLayers();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! Exactly what I was looking for. I just need to figure out how to get the other functions to work in this setup. Many thanks.

Comment: your welcome ;) do you mean the loading of the reports? http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/yrbru3sn/

Comment: would also work as a dialog http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/ka9ccb6f/

Comment: Is this caching the data? If I understand correctly the layer is being cleared and reloaded from the server on every map move.