# Where to create a web map of polygons and 50,000+ points?

Tags: web-mapping

I was using the qgis2web plugin to create a web map of polygons. I got this far: vehiclethefts.netne.net
Then, I had to add another layer containing 50,000 points and realized the plugin couldn't handle it. So, it crashes and you can not navigate on the map due to the large number of points.

So, I was wondering if there is a similar free service that would allow me make such a map of both polygons and points.

Comment: fusion tables? https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/181717?hl=en&ref_topic=27017

Answer (score 1):

Limit visibility of the layer to when you are more zoomed in, and add a bounding box strategy. See this question: [How to add a bounding box filter to this leaflet WFS request?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169129/how-to-add-a-bounding-box-filter-to-this-leaflet-wfs-request)

Comment: Are you suggesting I should I first generate the JS files with qgis2web and then modify the Javascript code? The problem is it's hard to load the index.html on the browser to even see what's going on.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Do you mean you are having difficulty finding the index.html file after export, to edit it? In the plugin dialog, use the setting `Data export > Export folder` to get the file to export somewhere you can find it.

Comment: I mean it's hard to test index.html on the browser as it barely loads. The plugin also crashes when generating all the points.

Comment: OK. Create a dummy dataset of about 100 points, evenly died across the range of your 50,000-point one, and swap that in while you code the functionality I mentioned above. Then swap back in you real dataset. That said, I don't think this is ever going to work with JSON layers. You need it to be from a WFS. The bbox strategy will only work in that situation.